# Appropriate to meet with prof. to discuss low quality exam

Tags: masters, exams

I am in an MBA program and last week had a two part test for a marketing class. I was under the impression the first part was just analysis, essentially creating models and writing notes on trends so you can quickly and easily answer the questions on the test (take home, given 3 hours to complete during the regularly scheduled class time).

The first part was much more extensive and actually had 6 questions with 3 sub questions per question to answer and I would've liked to have spent 12-15 hours on it versus the 8 I allotted myself. Because of *my* poor planning, I produced incomplete work and the completed work was NOT up the quality I usually produce and expect of myself. I did email my professor to ask for a possible extension and explain my situation. He would take off 25% for turning it in the next day, I did not take this option as I felt I could do better than that turning it in by 11 pm that night.

I am embarrassed and humbled. My professor is a very nice guy and a great teacher.

**Would it be appropriate to schedule a time to meet with him to discuss the quality of my exam and how I would have approached it differently?**

I am not looking for brownie points or extra credit or anything of the like. I just can't stop thinking about how I would have approached some of the questions differently. My ego took a hit and I'm essentially looking for redemption in a way.

Comment: I'm not sure the professor cares about what you could have written if you had had more time. I wouldn't like to meet a student with the mindset that you present in your question and comments. Your ego is your own problem. If it were me you would have left a worse impression after the meeting.

Comment: @ShakeBaby I appreciate the feedback and have decided to not meet with him. Although I think it would put myself at ease, there is no benefit for him personally or professionally so it is a waste of his time. He's aware of the situation I was in and I'm sure will take that into consideration as he reads my test. All I can do is make sure I don't put myself in the same situation again and let my _future_ work speak for itself.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If you would like to discuss the exam, schedule a meeting and talk with your professor about it. It seems that you have already discovered the core issues impacting your performance here - a lack of sufficient planning and the resulting lack of time - so it may be helpful to consider what you hope to learn from such a meeting. Are you hoping your professor knows some way to accomplish more work in less time? Are you looking for some confirmation that you really couldn't have done better? Your professor may have useful feedback but will likely agree with your assessments about planning.

Comment: I really just want redemption in his eyes. I feel sick thinking about him reading my answers for the questions and want to explain to him how I would've answered them differently if I had not been crunched on time. It's a personal issue where I don't like looking "stupid." I don't necessarily expect feedback from him but will happily accept any he has to offer.

Comment: His feedback will likely be "plan better next time". You know this. The most effective way to receive redemption will be to **show** your professor what your work looks like when you plan properly rather than to **tell** him.

Comment: I fully intend on **showing** the quality of work I product for the project and the final exam. So, essentially, it would be okay for me to meet with him but I shouldn't expect much out of the meeting.

Comment: Yes, by showing I mean show your work in the future, not showing what you could have done.

Answer (score 2):

There is one issue that might be worth discussing with the professor: Was the test expected to take as long as you estimate it would have taken you?

If so, you just need to improve your project planning, to allow for the possibility that an important task with a hard deadline will take longer than expected.

If the test should have only taken 8 hours for a properly prepared student, you have a more serious problem.

Answer (score -1):

Well your prof is not your therapist but s/he might consider it all in a day's work anyway. Marks to be deserved for every part of a question were always indicated clearly on my exam. The 100% to be earned was thus visibly chopped up in fragments no larger than 5%. Students could and would time-manage accordingly. If your exam paper was not laid out that way, suggesting this to the prof would be an objectively sensible thing to do (and might balm your ego in the process).